# My IP address is being blocked when accessing the trilogy sites

Tags: support, ip-ban

I have been using Stack Overflow and mostly Server Fault now for a while. Just yesterday when I go to any of the websites (serverfault.com, stackoverflow.com, meta.stackoverflow.com, and superuser.com) I am blocked by a 403 Forbidden page.

It seems to be related to my corporate static IP address which is 69.92.251.82 Luckily, I have a much slower [DSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_subscriber_line) connection with a different IP address and everything works just fine. What did I do that go me blocked? I don't screen scrape or anything of that nature; I even look at the ads. :)

Comment: Try running a tcptraceroute to see where you're being blocked, in case it's your company doing it like Andrew mentioned

Comment: Do other people with the same IP address use SO? Have they done something ban-worthy?

Comment: As I stated to him, this is not the case, although I understand your comment may have been left before I explained it more completely.

Comment: @mmyers I doubt it, I am the only "geeky" person that works here although it is possible I guess. We do have open wi-fi that anyone could connect to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend emailing the team.  They should be able to get things sorted out for you.

team@stackoverflow.com

Comment: excellent suggestion, was this somewhere and I just missed it?

Comment: @Matt, his answer was here long before your question appeared, you just had to wait until it materialized.

Comment: It's the 'contact us' link at the bottom of the page :)

Comment: wow... now I feel sheepish...

Comment: emailing the team worked well, and it turns out I hit their website 4,131 times in a day. My hunch is my RSS reader went crazy on the feeds I follow. Thanks everyone for all of your help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered that your business may be blocking traffic to Stack Overflow and not the other way around?

Comment: I am the system admin so I know this is not the case, plus I doubt I would get a 403, I would likely get a time out 404 or something of that nature correct?

Comment: @Matt: You would get a timeout, not a 404. A 404 is if it can resolve the domain but cannot find the specified file. A timeout implies you can't connect to the domain.

Comment: @Eric thanks for the explination, but I wouldn't get a 403 either correct?

Comment: **@Matt:** If all requests are passing by a proxy, the proxy could give you a 403.